# How do I add my property sheets faster in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am using Property Sheets to setup project properties. When I add a project to my solution I add the 3 property sheets (one shared between debug and release, one for debug and one for release). I have to right click both debug and release in the property manager, navigate to the folder containing the .props files every time.
Since I am often adding new projects to the solution, this is tiresome.

Project

Debug:

- property sheet a
- property sheet b

Release:

- property sheet a
- property sheet c

Is there a way to do this faster and more conveniently? Can I add solution-wise properties?

Comment: You can create a project template, now supported in VS2012.  File + Export Template.  Some jiggering is required, it forgets to include  the .props files.  Just edit the created .zip archive by hand.

Comment: I added the .props files to the .zip but I still have to add them manually to the project folder after creating the a project from the template. It is solving one problem but (at least in the current bugged state) creating a new problem. Thank you for the hint though.

Comment: Don't forget to add them to the .vstemplate file.

Comment: I forgot about that! I will try that when I get home.